# CURL command not indexing large data into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have exported a bunch of data (500 000 records) from legacy RDBMS database to a flat file in json format like:

```
{"index", {"_id": 1}}
{"Name": "Jack"}
...
{"index", {"_id": 500000}}
{"Name": "Joe"}
```

I'm trying to index this file into Elasticsearch using the CURL command, but the CURL command simply exits without indexing any data and without any message.

This is the CURL command:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/person/_doc/_bulk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@person_data.json"
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? or the CURL command is not capable to send large data (though its approximately 175MB)?

I'm running a large join query which takes a lot time in getting all the 500k rows from the RDBMS. Then I export these records into a json format in a file so that elasticsearch bulk API can consume it. However, as I can see the CURL command simply fails to index such a huge data without any error message.

In such case is there any GUI/Console tool to index the data in bulk?

Comment: how about trying to index with small dataset? will it result same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting, called `http.max_content_length` in the Elasticsearch, which configures the maximum size of http content.

By default it's equal to 100mb, that's why you couldn't index it properly. So, you need to change it and restart Elasticsearch. Maximum possible value is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

More information on it - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: Thanks it works but now it throws some json parse exception, I'll have to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: i would recommend you to create another question with json parse exception, and i will try to help you with it